# Reemplazar palabras con span en contenteditable

Tags: javascript

Quiero reemplazar todas las palabras por span, mi codigo es el siguiente:

```js
let written = '';
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  var palabra = written;
  written += String.fromCharCode(e.which);
  if (e.which === 32) {
    let text = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
    console.log(text);
    var wordsWithSpan = text.split(' ').map(function(c) {
      return '<span class="word">' + c + '</span>';
    }).join('');

    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = wordsWithSpan;
  }

});
```

```css
.word {
  color: red;
  padding-right: 2px;
}

div {
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="test">hola mundo tierra</div>
```

Por el momento solo funciona con el primer intento(**aprieten barra espaciadora**), desde el segundo intento obtengo el texto pero con etiquetas `span` en texto **plano**.

Lo que necesito es obtener en nodos no en texto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que cada vez que insertas un caracter, tienes que chequear por la presencia de spans y removerlos, para simplemente manipular el texto.  Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
let written = '';
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  var palabra = written;
  written += String.fromCharCode(e.which);
  if (e.which === 32) {
    let text = document.getElementById('test');
    let spans = text.getElementsByTagName('span');
    if (spans.length > 0) {
      text = '';
      for (var i = 0; i< spans.length; i++) {
        text += spans[i].innerHTML + ' ';
      }
      text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
    } else {
      text = text.innerHTML;
    }
    console.log(text);
    var wordsWithSpan = text.split(' ').map(function(c) {
      return '<span class="word">' + c + '</span>';
    }).join('');

    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = wordsWithSpan;
  }

});
```

```css
.word {
  color: red;
  padding-right: 2px;
}

div {
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="test">hola mundo tierra</div>
```

Comment: Te puedo preguntar cual es el proposito de este funcionamiento?

Comment: Chequea este post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233265/contenteditable-set-caret-at-the-end-of-the-text-cross-browser

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener el texto se usa `textContent`... Lo que hago es capturar el texto que se muestra dentro del `div`, y luego separarlo por espacios mediante una expresión regular `/[\b\s\n]+/gi`, entonces vuelvo a asignar el contenido del `div`, pero esta vez convertido a palabras con `span`.

El problema con asignar otra vez el contenido es que se pierde la posición del cursor... Para esto se puede hacer una función que cambie el cursor.

> Nota: En mi ejemplo el cursor no funciona completamente bien, parece que se teletransporta... A fin de cuentas, es solo como demostración.

Para agregar espacios al final de la palabra hago `<a> </a>`. Aunque podría haber agregado solamente un espacio mediante `innerHTML`, recomiendo usar `appendChild`... Por ese mismo motivo es que el cursor vuelve al principio, porque estoy usando `innerHTML`, y además, determinar la posición cuando hay varios `<span>` mezclado en la estructura *HTML* es una tarea complicada.

> Para que se note que está agrupado en `span`, puse un fondo de otro color en cada palabra.

```js
function asignar_posición(div,posición)
{
 var range = document.createRange()
 var sel = window.getSelection()
 range.setStart(div, posición)
 range.collapse(true)
 sel.removeAllRanges()
 sel.addRange(range)
}
function obtener_posición_final_selección() {
 return document
  .defaultView.getSelection()
  .getRangeAt(0).startOffset
}
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
 var test = document.querySelector("#test")
 var texto = document.querySelector("#test").textContent
 var posición = obtener_posición_final_selección()
 test.innerHTML = ""
 texto.split(/[\b\s\n]+/gi).map(
  function(x){
   var span = document.createElement("span")
   var a = document.createElement("a")
   span.className = "word"
   span.style["background-color"] = "#abcd"
   span.innerHTML = x
   a.innerHTML = " \n"
   test.appendChild(span)
   test.appendChild(a)
  }
 )
 try{
  asignar_posición(test,posición)
 }catch(e){}
});
```

```css
#test{
 background-color:#0123;
 font-size:33px
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="test">hola mundo tierra</div>
```

Comment: alguna idea para que el cursor no se teletransporte?